# Type with generics not being correctly inferred?

Tags: typescript, generics

```
interface A {
    a1: string;
    a2: number;
}

interface B {
    b1: number;
    b2: number;
}

interface Data {
    a?: A;
    b?: B;
}

const parseA = (x: string): A => ({ a1: '', a2: 0 });
const parseB = (x: string): B => ({ b1: 0, b2: 0 });

const parse = <K extends keyof Data>(name: string, value: string): [K, Required<Data>[K]] => {
    switch (name) {
        case 'a': return [name, parseA(value)];
        case 'b': return [name, parseB(value)];
        default: throw new Error('invalid input');
    }
}

const test: ['a', A] | ['b', B] = parse('', '');
```

Error is reported on line with `case 'a'` (and similar with `case 'b'`):

```
Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'K'.
  '"a"' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '"a" | "b"'.(2322)
```

I don't think the error message makes any sense. I would expect a type of a returned value to be `['a', A]`, because `name` must be in this branch `'a'`, a second item of returned pair must be `A`. Same goes with the `'b'` branch.

**Do I have an error somewhere, or TypeScript compiler is not smart enough to infer/validate this kind of a constraint? Is it possible to fix/rewrite it in a type-safe manner?**

Comment: I had a similar issue in the past, I remember that changing the signature to `const parse = (name: string, value: string): [keyof Data, Required<Data>[keyof Data]]` might fix the problem, but I don't think I fully understand why

Comment: @bugs I don't think it's the same. I want `['a', A] | ['b', B]` to be inferred, but I suspect your approach would result into `['a' | 'b', A | B]`, so invalid results would be allowed (e.g. `['a', B]` or `['b', A]`).